# How to set a column width fixed in excel?

Tags: excel, width, column-width

I have a pivot table in Excel with a few filters.
There a particular columns in filter that contain large data and a few columns that have small data. So I want to fix the column size to a particular value so that whenever I change the filter in the pivot table the size of column remains same.
I have added an example below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I want to fix the size of column A no matter how the filter changes its width remains same. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `PivotTable Options` and clear `Autofit column withs on update` checkbox:

[image]